# Why is my Winforms Application MessageFilter not dispatching messages?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a .Net Winforms application.
I'm trying to add message filtering via IMessageFilter.

The filter gets added correctly and I am intercepting messages.
For purposes I am returning false, so all messages should dispatch and processed.

However, once the filter starts intercepting messages, the messages do not get dispatched to normal filtering/processing.

I'm not sure what's going here. Is this the correct way to intercept/filter messages in a Winforms application? I would like to be able to use this filter to examine information about the winforms controls receiving the events.

**Here is my sample MessageFilter class:**

```
public class InspectorMessageFilter : IMessageFilter
{
    public bool PreFilterMessage(ref Message message)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

**Here is the code to instantiate and add the filter:**

```
var filter = new InspectorMessageFilter();
Application.AddMessageFilter(filter);
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed my Prefilter definition to:

```
public class InspectorMessageFilter : IMessageFilter
{
    public bool IMessageFilter.PreFilterMessage(ref Message message)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

It all works now!

Comment: That seems highly unlikely since this code should generate a compiler error - [CS0106](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0106?f1url=%3FappId%3Droslyn%26k%3Dk(CS0106)) - since you cannot combine access modifiers with explicit interface implementation.

Comment: Works fine like a charm and based on HWnd I can access the control target.

Comment: No, you changed one or more things. One of them *may* have been to make your interface implementation explicit but a) that shouldn't in itself resolve the problem and b) you cannot use `public` with an explicit interface implementation. The *literal* code you've shown in this answer doesn't compile on any version of C# and the difference between it and what's shown in your question doesn't make a difference. I could just look at this code and get a gut feeling that it wouldn't compile but I've also *verified* that it doesn't compile.

Comment: Apologies, you are correct. Looking back at source with fresh eyes I see I don't have it declared as public.